# Make table content center but align left

Tags: html, css

I want to use table to do a legend for a chart. I created an example to show the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/s3mf64gq

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel col-md-12">
      <table class="table borderless">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Jane - Software Engineer
            </td>
            <td>
              John - Senior Marketing Executive
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Teddy - CEO
            </td>
            <td>
              James - Lecturer
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 requirements:

1. all of the item must be align to the left
2. the container must be center to the parent

How to solve it? I'm stuck.

The challenge is the length of the items is not equal, otherwise I would simply do text-align center on the `td` then it's solved.

Comment: What does the parent look like ? How are you setting the width of the container ? Have you considered using flexbox instead of table ?

Comment: In your fiddle, the container div is centred with your td items left aligned, I don't understand what you are wanting, please could you explain a bit more

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is supposed to be left aligned, and what is supposed to be centered?

Comment: @Pete it's not center visually, technically yes.

Comment: @Jay sorry I know what's hard to explain with words, here's what I want to achieve. https://i.imgur.com/YtP0zOv.png visually center a 'table'

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get onto imgur through the office firewall.

Comment: So this - https://jsfiddle.net/rkgjqu78/

Comment: Me either, banned: Your request was denied because of its content categorization: "Media Sharing;Mixed Content/Potentially Adult"

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks so much, but I have to use padding left and right for my td. Imagine I have different block of container which have different width, how would u cater that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `.table` class has a predefined `width` of `100%`, you need to set it to `auto` so the `<table>` will be sized by its content.

Then by adding `margin: 0 auto` it will center horizontally.

```
.table {
  margin: 0 auto;           /*  horizontally center  */
  width: auto;              /*  reset the built in value of 100%  */
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3mf64gq/1/)

Stack snippet

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  background: #eee;
}

.borderless td,
.borderless th {
  border: none !important;
}

.table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel col-md-12">
      <table class="table borderless">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Jane - Software Engineer
            </td>
            <td>
              John - Senior Marketing Executive
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Teddy - CEO
            </td>
            <td>
              James - Lecturer
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much, but I have to use padding left and right for my td. Imagine I have different block of container which have different width, how would u cater that?

Comment: @CeciliaChan I haven't changed any padding left or right, so can you explain what you mean by that? ... and with different block of container with different width, please post an updated fiddle showing how that looks like so I can suggest a solution.

Comment: just image your table is within 2 different container with class of `col-md-4` and `col-md-8`. it won't spread nicely if I hardcode the padding like `padding: 0 20px;`

Comment: @CeciliaChan I still don't understand what you mean with padding. You also haven't mention anything like it in the question, which you are suppose to. Could you please provide a fiddle showing what you mean?